# Meaning of $^sB$, s an element, B a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, notation

Let $G = SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$, $B$ the subgroup of all upper triangular matrices, $s = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

What does $^sB$ mean?

I read it from page 4 of C. Bonnafé, *Representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$*, but there's no definition.

There's also a statement saying $B \cap {}^sB = T$, which is the subgroup of all diagonal matrices.

Comment: This is just a guess, but could it be $sBs^{-1}$? This might be to distinguish it from $B^s = s^{-1}Bs$.

Comment: $s^{-1}Bs \cap B = T$ is also true though. He's not using this kind of notation anywhere else, so I'll go with your guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$^sB=sBs^{-1}$ is defined at the beginning of the book (page xxi "General notation"). It seems that that notation for a group action is more common in Cohomology.

Comment: That's shameful of me... I should've checked the TOC first. I only have chapter 1 at hand.